# Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm new to selenium Python and been practicing the concepts using some websites. I'm stuck with the below issues.

1. While i open this website (https://www.shoppersstop.com/) and click on brands, I'm getting a cookies popup:

   ```
   We use cookies to give you the best experience and analyze the site use. By continuing your browsing, you accept their use.

   Find out more about cookies in Privacy Policy.
   ```

Can anyone help me how can i close this pop-up though its not alert?

2. When I hover on hautecurry then only i can see view now button which i have to click. can anyone help me with this as well?

Below is the code i have tried so far:

1. For closing the cookies popup :

   ```
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
   wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "closecookieExitButton")))        
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("close cookieExitButton").click()
   ```

I have used presence of element located, also element to be clickable but its not getting closed.

2. For clicking View Now button which gets visible only on mouse hover:

   ```
   action = ActionChains(driver)
   viewNow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/haute-curry']/span")
   action.move_to_element(viewNow).perform()
   viewNow.click()
   ```

It throws no element found exception though my customised xpath is unique.

Comment: Please write the code in block to better understand your question.

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/62034281/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_class_name()` only supports a single classname.

Try a CSS selector instead:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".close .cookieExitButton")
```

For your second issue, I cannot find the hautecurry thing in the website, but you first get the element and then you hover it, should be the other way around.

Comment: Thank you Niels, first one worked!! :) for the second one noe in the shopperstop website wen we click on brands driver.get("http://www.shoppersstop.com")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("BRANDS").click()  and here if we see there is HauteCurry box where wen we mouse over only 'View Now' is visible , My question is i have to click on this 'View Now' button which gets visible only on mouseover...Can you pls help??

Comment: First find the LI with the text "Haute Curry", then find the IMGelement in the LI, hover the IMG and then find the View Now link and click on it.